# What is $\beta_h$ in Hatcher?

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image]

I am puzzled what does $\beta_h$ refer to in this paragraph in Hatcher's book Algebraic Topology.

Any idea? Is it the induced homomorphism of $h$?

Ok, I found it in page 28.

$\beta_h$ is the change-of-basepoint map.

Comment: I have no idea why someone told you to delete your answer - it's a perfectly good, complete answer. (Maybe they'd like it better if you wrote out more precisely what the definition of $\beta_h$ was.) If you undelete and accept it, I'll upvote it.

Comment: Yeah Hatcher has a bad habit about introducing new notation in the middle of a proof and using it throughout the rest of the chapter without any reference

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found it in page 28.

$\beta_h$ is the change-of-basepoint map, $\beta_h:\pi_1(X,x_1)\to\pi_1(X,x_0)$ defined by $\beta_h[f]=[hf\bar{h}]$.